# Execute cmd-like command in Python

Tags: python, cmd, executable

I want to make a Python code that will open a program like cmd would, then export a .txt file from the file menu. The code looks like this for cmd:

```
c:\ESG\Statsvis.exe \\192.168.100.222\c\ESG\S1-424\2012\06\29\S1-42420120629.dsf /output=C:\Users\jessica.macleod\Desktop\outfile.txt /param=RMS Amplitude
```

In cmd, the above line does exactly what I want. What would be the equivalent for Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/ls", "-l"]
```

Or, depending on what you want to get as result (stdout, return code), use `subprocess.call`, `subprocess.call_check`, or other snippets in this module.

Comment: Hi defuz, I looked into this particular command, but I'm still not quite sure how it works. How does that call the command I have above? edit: by that, I mean the /output:

Comment: try something like this: `["c:\\ESG\\Statsvis.exe", "\\\\192.16...29.dsf", "/output=C:\\Users\\jessica.macleod\\Desktop\\outfile.txt", "/param=RMS", "Amplitude"]`

Comment: I have tried using the subprocess.call() command to open the program, but I'm still not quite sure how to tell it to execute the command. What would be the proper way to write the output path and the "param" that I want Python to execute?

Comment: Every \ must be escaped (replace to \\\), and command line must be split to list by whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be [os.system()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/os.html#os.system).

```
import os
os.system("c:\\ESG\\Statsvis.exe \\192.16...0629.dsf /output=C:\\...\\outfile.txt ...")
```

Comment: Backslashes in path will not be correctly interpreted in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have exact shell/cmd behavior, then set the `shell` argument to `True` in a `suprocess.Popen()` call. However, from the documentation:

> Warning
>
> Invoking the system shell with shell=True can be a security hazard if
>   combined with untrusted input. See the warning under Frequently Used
>   Arguments for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output of the command use subprocess:

```
import subprocess
out = subprocess.check_output("dir c:\ /AD", shell = True)
```